# gazebo on groovy ERROR

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install gazebo for groovy on fuerte.

first run :  rosws set --svn simulator_gazebo https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/groovy/

2. rosws update
3. rosmake simulator_gazebo

An i got this error:

```
-- BUILD ERRORS: These must be resolved before compiling.
  --    Missing: Ogre3d version >=1.7.1(http://www.orge3d.org)
  -- END BUILD ERRORS
```

and i was searching how get it , but doesn't work .

pd: i was trying others version of gazebo 'cause i need someone the collision works.

EDIT:

```
> Running rosdep install
> simulator_gazebo gazebo_tests: Cannot
> locate rosdep definition for
> [protobuf-dev] gazebo_tools: Cannot
> locate rosdep definition for
> [protobuf-dev] gazebo: Cannot locate
> rosdep definition for [protobuf-dev]
> gazebo_plugins: Cannot locate rosdep
> definition for [protobuf-dev]
> gazebo_worlds: Cannot locate rosdep
> definition for [protobuf-dev]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53560/gazebo-on-groovy-error/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-28**:
Did you intend to check out the Groovy version of gazebo to build on Fuerte?

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-01-28**:
yes, that is what i'm doing

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-28**:
What version of ogre do you have? Did you run rosdep install simulator_gazebo?

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-01-29**:
how can i know the version of ogre? i suppose i have that fuerte version get. And when i run rosdep install simulator_gazebo i have some errors, see EDIT Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You did not mention what OS you are running.

On Ubuntu Precise, I have OGRE 1.7.4-3, which seems to work fine:

```
$ dpkg -s libogre-dev
Package: libogre-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 6044
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: ogre
Version: 1.7.4-3
Depends: libogre-1.7.4 (= 1.7.4-3), libboost-date-time-dev, libboost-thread-dev, libfreeimage-dev, libfreetype6-dev, libzzip-dev, libxaw7-dev
Suggests: ogre-doc
Description: 3D Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine (development files)
 OGRE (Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine) is a scene-oriented, flexible
 3D engine written in C++ designed to make it easier and more intuitive for
 developers to produce applications utilising hardware-accelerated 3D
 graphics. The class library abstracts all the details of using the underlying
 system libraries like Direct3D and OpenGL and provides an interface based on
 world objects and other intuitive classes.
 .
 This package contains the headers needed to develop with OGRE.
Original-Maintainer: Debian Games Team <pkg-games-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Homepage: http://ogre3d.org/
```

Perhaps you just need to install that package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-01-29**:
thnks, i have to install ogre (sudo apt-get install libogre-dev) and make again "rosmake" and that's works thnks. the sad thing is that for my computer is so heavy. i'll go to try electric version.